# Correct way to remove ONE localization

Tags: iphone, localization

Seeing as the sv_SE localization doesn't take effect on the iPhone Simulator, but sv does (with the same language settings set to Swedish (language AND region), I would now like to remove the sv_SE localization to keep things proper.

What's the correct way to do this?

Do I really have to Remove All Localizations and re-do the translation work for the XIBs, as there seems no other way to do it in the Info window?

Mark localization in resources and delete? Delete folder/.lproj? Which is correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Xcode 3.2**: expand localizable file subtree in left pane (files & groups). Then delete the unwanted localization. You probably want to click "Also move to trash" button.

**Xcode 4**: select the file, show utilities sidebar (the right one), pick the "show file inspector" button. There is a section with localizations. Select the unwanted one, click minus (-) button. Confirm. Or do it like in Xcode 3.2 deleting the localization from the project navigator. , it's up to you.

**Xcode 5**: works like Xcode 4.

If you remove all localizations (by mistake for instance) you can add the `lproj` folders to the project. You don't need to make one by one localizable again.

Tip: better you commit your work, experiment, if your changes doesn't work checkout the previous version and try again.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did 5 minutes after asking the question, doh :) Backed up and experimented. Deleting in the tree seems to have worked fine. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @djromero! Wow, good, but if I want to LEAVE only one localization?

Comment: Hmm...remove one by one until there is only one? In that case may be faster to remove the unwanted stuff from lproj folder and adjust the project.

Comment: Just removed a localized string file on XCode 5 and the same procedure for XCode 4 worked on it too. @djromero you might update your answer to mention this.