# iOS removing localization

Tags: ios, localization

I had to remove some language localizations from my iOS application.
after removing those localization the languages do not appear in xcode.

The problem is that if a user (with one of the removed languages) updates the application he gets the old localizations

I managed to remove the old localizations by removing the old application version and installing the new version, but obviously i cant force my users to do that.

is there a way to force the removal of the old languages from the user's device?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this previously given answer [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549992/correct-way-to-remove-one-localization) localization. I hope it will help you.

Comment: I still need to remove the old application version from my device in order not to see the old localization